# Adding data from a CSV file into a Struct

Tags: c, csv, struct

I was wondering how I'd add data I've read from a CSV file into a Struct (would a Struct even be the best way to go?). My CSV file is just 4 values under a header (x,y,u,v). The plan would be to store the data (without the header), and then manipulate it and/or perform calculations with it. 
The file reads fine, I'm just confused what to do with it, once it's opened.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "tasks.h"

typedef struct {
    float xvalue;
    float yvalue;
    float uvalue;
    float vvalue;
} flow_data;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

char* flow_file = NULL;
int resolution = 0;

flow_file = argv[2];
resolution = atoi(argv[3]);

// Reading flow_data.csv
FILE* flow_fileopen = fopen(flow_file, "r");

// Checking if the file has been read succesfully
if( flow_fileopen == NULL)
{
    perror("Error opening file");
    exit(1);
}

// Wasn't sure how to find the entry count, so I manually set it for now.
int entry_count = 7;

flow_data *dataset = malloc(sizeof(flow_fileopen) * entry_count);

char c;

do {
    c = fgetc(flow_fileopen);
    printf("%c", c );
} while (c != EOF);

free(dataset);
```

What the data set looks like

```
x y u v
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Can you tell how stored in the .csv file . column wise  or continuous  data . Sample input if you share so that i can help you out.

Comment: Columns, so all the x values would be under x, all the y under y, etc. X and Y would be coordinates and U and V velocities.

Comment: One usually chooses how to store data based on what they need to do with the data.  Generally you choose a data-structure that makes your most frequent operations efficient.  In your case, if you're just playing around, start with an `struct` that has fields for each column (e.g., `int x; int y; int u; int v;` and try to read one row into the struct, parsing the characters into integers.  Next make an array of the structs, and try to read one line into each array index.  Then move on to making a linked-list of structs, so that you can read files with an arbitrary number of lines. see `fscanf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> flow_data *dataset = malloc(sizeof(flow_fileopen) * entry_count);
> ```

`flow_fileopen` is a pointer and `sizeof(flow_fileopen)` is just the size of pointer (4 or 8 for example). You want `sizeof(flow_data)` instead. You can also use `sizeof(*dataset)` which maybe less prone to typing error.

Once you allocate enough memory, you can use `fscanf` to read each line, and save to the structure. If `fscanf` is successful, it returns the number of fields it reads. Make sure you skip the first line which holds the field names "x y u v".

```
int entry_count = 7;
flow_data* dataset = malloc(sizeof(*dataset) * entry_count);

//skip the first line which includes field names
char buf[500];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), flow_fileopen);

int total = 0;
while(1)
{
    flow_data* p = &dataset[total];
    if(4 != fscanf(flow_fileopen, "%f %f %f %f\n",
        &p->xvalue, &p->yvalue, &p->uvalue, &p->vvalue))
    break;
    total++;
    if(total == entry_count)
        break; //this array can only hold a maximum of `entry_count`
}
```

Instead of guessing how many lines there are in the file, use `realloc` to increase the size of the array as needed.

```
int main() 
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("flow_data.csv", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buf[500];
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp); //skip the first line

    int total = 0;
    flow_data d;
    flow_data* dataset = NULL;
    while(4 == fscanf(fp, "%f %f %f %f\n", &d.xvalue, &d.yvalue, &d.uvalue, &d.vvalue))
    {
        dataset = realloc(dataset, sizeof(*dataset) * (total + 1));
        dataset[total] = d;
        total++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        flow_data* p = &dataset[i];
        printf("%.1f, %.1f, %.1f, %.1f\n", p->xvalue, p->yvalue, p->vvalue, p->uvalue);
    }

    free(dataset);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, sorry for the late reply. I've tried this code but it doesn't print anything. Would the "%f %f %f %f\n" part of fscanf work, if the values are separated by a comma, like in a CSV file?

Comment: Alright I changed that, it works now, thank you for your help.